# Error when using Bitmap.SetSource

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bitmapimage

I'm working on an app which loads images from a chosen folder to a gridView.

when I use SetSource to set the BitmapImage source I receive an error "insufficient memory" after loading some of the images.

when I use the constructor with a Uri path it works fine. but it will only display images from the projects directory.

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(RecentToken);
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));//loads only within project directory
image.SetSource(stream);//causes insufficient memory
stream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
I set the BitmaPimage's DecodePixelHeight to the size of the Displayed image and it works fine now!